# Passing a value to a function that accepts a reference

Tags: c++, function, pointers

In the following example `sin.connect` accepts a `const reference`. Why both `sig.connect(printHello);` and `sig.connect(&printHello);` compile without problems and produce the same result? What is the difference between passing a val and ref to a function that accept a reference?

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void printHello()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
    sig.connect(printHello); // <- slot reference
    sig.connect(&printHello); // <- slot
    // sig.connect(const slot_type &slot) <- signature
    sig();
}
```

Comment: Functions are automatically converted to pointers to themselves most of the time, including here.

Comment: So in this example it’s the same right? Is there any case that we need to explicitly need to pass it with & ??

Comment: Here yes, they're same. No, you don't need `&` 99% of the time. It's [possible to write a function](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/461rsh) that will only accept other functions with `&`, but there's no reason to do that. Note that the situation is completely different with non-static member functions.